# Cronjob spring boot on startup

Tags: java, spring, cron, boot

У меня стоит задача написать cronjob, которая будет при запуске приложения загружать данные из ДБ, я нашла такую информацию "@reboot: Schedule the method for every reboot of the application"
но такая запись не работает @Scheduled(cron = "@reboot"),
как правильно указать cron?

Comment: на сколько я знаю, cronjob оперирует понятиями временных промежутков, а не событий запуска/остановки приложений. Вам именно на кронджобах надо это реализовать?

Comment: да я и сама понимаю что cronjob это не совсем для этого, но в ТЗ написанно именно cronjob

Comment: Для чего там расписание вообще не понятно. Для запуска метода после загрузки  приложения есть  - @PostConstruct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось это была ошибка в ТЗ

Answer (score 0):

`@reboot` - нестандартное выражение поддерживаемое [crontab](https://crontab.guru/), которое обозначает время (ре)старта системы, а не время запуска Вашего приложения.

Как уже писали в комментах, cron не поддерживает события запуска приложения итд.

Очевидно в ТЗ cronjob используется не в техническом смысле, а в более широком, подразумевая асинхронную операцию привязанную к определенному событию (это конечно желательно уточнить)

Если так, то можно использовать все возможные способы, например

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts
- https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Если все же необходимо использовать cron, тогда можно задать период - например в полночь `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")` - а в коде уже проверять и игнорировать повторные вызовы.